# Error when generating R package manual

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex

I having the following issue when trying to check a package using the command line. 
First I get this very general error message:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index … ERROR
```

Then, when I check Rdlatex log, I found the following complain:

```
Transcript written on Rd2.log.
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  unable to run 'pdflatex' on 'Rd2.tex'
Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
You may want to clean up by 'rm -rf /var/folders/_q/_kj9kz0n0qq_gwkrv9qjvpxw0000gn/T//Rtmp7uzkmZ/Rd2pdf2a847787e63'
```

For some reason it didn't manage to run pdflatex though it is properly installed as the following testifies. Does anyone has a clue on how I can fix it?

> system("pdflatex --version")
>   pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
>   kpathsea version 6.2.0
>   Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
>   covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
>   the Lesser GNU General Public License.
>   For more information about these matters, see the file
>   named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
>   Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
>   Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
>   Compiled with xpdf version 3.03

Very weirdly, running R CMD Rd2pdf man/ produces output.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/local/texlive/2014bas
ic/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/inconsolata/i4-ts1.enc}{/usr/local/texlive/2014ba
sic/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}{/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-
dist/fonts/enc/dvips/inconsolata/i4-t1-0.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/inconsolata/Inconsolata-zi4r.pfb></usr/local/texlive/
2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/local/texl
ive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/
texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb></usr/loc
al/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/
local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr5.pfb></us
r/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></
usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pf
b></usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7
.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.p
fb></usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb></
usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/l
ocal/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/local/
texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on Rd2.pdf (62 pages, 264746 bytes).
Transcript written on Rd2.log.
Saving output to 'Rd2.pdf' ...
Done
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your Rd files. Please, post what it is saying after `ERROR`. What happens when you try to produce the manual through `R CMD Rd2pdf man/` in your package directory?

Comment: Very weirdly : R CMD Rd2pdf man/ produces an output without error:

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use a font that can't implement all of the characters in your Rd files. Can I take it from the name of the package that you're trying to create some kind of alternative to the standard package documentation?

Comment: I have installed Tex Live by this command: `apt-get install texlive`.

Answer (score 0):

I had `R CMD check` and `R CMD Rd2pdf` fail because one of our collabs created an empty curly-braces block that was not escaped by roxygen and broke the laTeX render, .i.e. the `\dontrun{}` below :

```
#' An example of breaking the R CMD Rd2pdf with unescaped curly braces.
#'
#' @param df A dataframe.
#' @return A dataframe.
#'
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' }
#' @export
funcname <- function(df){
df
}
```